# Understanding struct initialiser if it contain private property

Tags: swift, struct

I want to understand how initialiser work if **struct** contains **private properties**. I have following code:

```
struct Doctor {
    var name: String
    var location: String
    private var currentPatient = "No one"
}
let drJones = Doctor(name: "Esther Jones", location: "Bristol")
```

This throws an error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Doctor' with an argument list of
>   type '(name: String, location: String)'

My Assumption is: ***Default Memeberwise initialiser contains private property which can't be called from outside.***

But I am confused by following code:

```
struct Doctor {
    private var currentPatient = "No one"
}
let drJones = Doctor()
```

How this is working?, it is not throwing any error.

Comment: The reason is simple `.init()` without parameters is not a *default memberwise initializer* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use default memberwise initialiser for assigning `struct`'s property with `private` access level modifier.

Your second example works, because you gave your property default value so there is no need to assign it while you're initalizing it.

If you need to assign your private property using initializer, you have to write your own

```
init(name: String, location: String, currentPatient: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.location = location
    self.currentPatient = currentPatient
}
```

Comment: I understood that default memebrwise initialiser can't be used because of private access.  In second example, which initialiser getting called? init()?

Comment: @FaisalIkwal it is in my answer. Because you gave your property default value initalizer without parameters (`init()`) is called since you don’t need to assign any properties